# Prevent or evade a revert when fallback is not written in target contract

Tags: solidity

i have a question
i have a token contract that has a function
`function add(address _target) public`
and i have another contract that call this one

```
interface Token{
    function add(address _target) external;
}

contract Test{
    address public target;
    function callToken(address _token) public {
        target = _token;
        Token(_token).add(address(this));
    }
}
```

Now i want to change the target token , but the problem is there's no function called add in the new token , and there's no fallback also
Is there any way i can prevent this call from reverting and changing the variable target to the new token
Note that all the contracts are already deployed and i can't change the code
i was hoping to use some sort of proxy logic or something to be able to do it

thank you

Edit :
I know that before solidity 0.5.0 a call to a non existent function didn't revert , no way to choose something like an old evm version or smth like that ?

Answer (score 1):

use a low level call, like this :

```js
contract Test{
    address public target;
    function callToken(address _token) public {
        target = _token;
        (bool s, bytes memory returndata) = target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(address)", address(this));
    // s will be set to false if the call reverts
        if(s == false) {
          //do something
        }
        else{
          // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use try/catch, like this :

```js
 interface Token{
    function add(address _target) external;
}

contract Test{
    address public target;
    function callToken(address _token) public {
        target = _token;
        try Token(target).add(address(this)) {
          // If  success, do something
        } catch {
          // If revert, do something else
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : Since `Test` is already deployed, same logic but you're going to call it instead :

```js
contract TestWrapper{
  address TestContract;
  function callTest(address target) external {
    (bool s, bytes memory returndata) = TestContract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("callToken(address)", target);
    // s will be set to false if the call reverts
        if(s == false) {
          //do something
        }
        else{
          // do something else
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution since the OP said the contracts are already deployed. Also by using low level call with fixed selector the smart contract will face the same problem

Comment: This isnt how i understood it. I assumed `Test` wasnt deployed. But if that's the case, that doesnt change anything, just deploy a contract that calls `Test` as i indicated, and the low level call does fix the problem (as in, it won't revert the whole transaction)

Comment: yeah thank you for the answer but unfortunately the contract is already deployed

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution for the case Test is already deployed @benbitcoin

Comment: Oh ok , thank you i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Without the development of another smart contract you cannot solve anything. The function selector is included in transaction Data and you have a fixed selector.